# Search api solr result reordering on field value

Tags: 7, search, views

I'm using [search_api_solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) and [search_api_location](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_location). I have a view with exposed filters to perform geolocation searches.

I'm trying to reorder search result from a solr query based a referenced node's field. My question is witch hook to use, **where i can access node fields and reorder the results.**

I already tried:

- hook_views_pre_render()
- hook_views_post_execute()
- hook_views_post_render()
- hook_views_pre_view()

but reordering is effectless or i don't have access to node fields.
I'm doing something like this:

```
$results = &$view->result;
$to_search_top = array();
foreach ( $results as $i => $capacity){
  if ((int) $capacity->{_entity_properties}['field_free_capacity_company_ref:field_last_review'] > 1) {
    unset($results[$i]);
    $to_search_top[] = $capacity;
  }
}

foreach ($to_search_top as $capa) {
  array_unshift($results, $capa);
}
```

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i was only able to solve this with hook_preprocess_views_view_table().

```
$to_search_top = array();
foreach ($vars['rows'] as $index => $row) {
  if ((int) $row['field_company_review_number_1'] > 0) {
    $to_search_top[] = $row;
    unset($vars['rows'][$index]);
  }
}

// Sort reviewed by distance.
usort($to_search_top, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['field_free_capacity_coordinates_latlon'] == $item2['field_free_capacity_coordinates_latlon']) {
            return 0;
    }
    return $item1['field_free_capacity_coordinates_latlon'] > $item2['field_free_capacity_coordinates_latlon'] ? -1 : 1;
 });

// Move to results top.
foreach ($to_search_top as $row) {
  array_unshift($vars['rows'], $row);
}
```